# Fonts not loading in Mathematica running in IIS

Tags: iis-7, service, fonts, wolfram-mathematica, session-0-isolation

I am using The [.NET/Link for mathematica](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/NETLink/tutorial/Overview.html) in my Asp.Net application (running under IIS 7.5) but am having issues where some of the custom fonts that Mathematica uses do not show up.

For example the character Pi doesn't show up.  It should look like: [image: Expected] but actually looks like: [image].

This problem only happens on one particular machine, and only when running it in IIS, if I create this image in a Console App (or even using IIS Express) then the image is created just fine.

For those with some experience with .NET/Link the code I am using to create the images is:

```
IKernelLink ml = MathLinkFactory.CreateKernelLink();
ml.WaitAndDiscardAnswer();
Image img = ml.EvaluateToTypeset("HoldForm[x Pi x]", 0);
context.Response.ContentType = "image/gif";
img.Save(context.Response.OutputStream, ImageFormat.Gif);
ml.Close();
```

But I don't believe an understanding of that is a requirement, as I believe its solely an issue with loading the font and using it in IIS.

So, I guess the meat of the question is: Is there any reason that IIS (or any Windows Service) wouldn't be able to read/process a font besides permission issues (since I tried running the service as Admin).

Comment: Have you checked that that particular machine doesn't have its own copy of the fonts, which are conflicting? If the fonts are old and corrupted, or just encoded differently, it could be causing an issue.

Comment: Yea, I even uninstalled Mathematica, deleted the fonts and then reinstalled Mathematica to make sure that wasn't the issue.

Comment: Is the font version on the machine newer than the one IIS references?

Comment: IIS references the one in C:\Windows\Fonts\ (which is the same one that is used when runinng it outside of IIS?) So...I think the answer to your question is, "no".

Comment: I am out of ideas, then. Sorry I could not help further.